# Getting custom HTML to show in homepage.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to add some simple HTML to the homepage of a client's WordPress website.  At first, I added the code to the header.php and everything looked and worked how it should; but, then I realised that it was showing on every page when I just need it on the home page.

So, I tried adding the same HTML after the get_header in the homepage.php and then in the index.php but nothing shows at all when I add the code to these pages.

No matter where I put the HTML in homepage.php or index.php it will not show. I'm new to WordPress as you have no doubt gathered.

Do I need to make a template or use some code to introduce the HTML in either of these two pages? Why does it show in the header.php?

I tried using with no joy:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
```

The home page code is here if it helps:

```
    <?php
/**
Template Name: Homepage
*
*/
get_header(); ?>
<?php $general_options = get_option( 'meanthemes_theme_general_options' ); ?>
<?php $content_options = get_option ( 'meanthemes_theme_content_options' ); ?>
<?php if( isset( $general_options[ 'hide_slider' ] ) ) {
// do nothing
} else {
?>
<section class="hero flexslider">
<article class="wrapper">
<div class="flex-container"></div>
<ul class="slides">
<?php
$bannerPortfolio = $general_options[ 'swap_slider' ];
if(!$bannerPortfolio) {
query_posts( array ( 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<li>
<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
<div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo excerpt_clip(get_the_excerpt(), '28'); ?> <?php _e('[...]','meanthemes'); ?></a>
</div>
<time class="time" datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d', '', ''); ?>"><?php the_time('jS M Y') ?></time>
</li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php
} else {
?>
<?php
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'desc', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
<hgroup>
<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
<div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo excerpt_clip(get_the_excerpt(), '48'); ?> <?php _e('[...]','meanthemes'); ?></a></div>
</hgroup>
</li>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</article><!-- / article.wrapper -->
</section>
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "fade", // animation type fade or slide
          slideshowSpeed: <?php echo sanitize_text_field( $general_options    ['slider_timer'] ); ?>, // sections between transitions
          directionNav: true, // show previous and back
          controlNav: false,
          controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
    });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
<?php if( $general_options[ 'show_portfolio' ] ) { ?>

    <section class="wrapper portfolio">
        <article>
            <hgroup>
                <h2><?php echo balanceTags( $content_options['we_do'] ); ?></h2>
            </hgroup>
            <div><?php echo balanceTags( $content_options['we_do_summary'] ); ?></div>
        </article>
        <?php
        query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'desc' ) );
    ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <aside>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-thumb'); ?></a>
                <hgroup>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </hgroup>
                <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo excerpt_clip(get_the_excerpt(), '14'); ?><?php _e('[...]','meanthemes'); ?></a></div>
            </aside>
<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('body').addClass("home");
});
</script>
<?php get_footer();  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howlin's example should work. Another solution is to create a `front-page.php` in the theme-directory, copy the content from the page.php to it, and add your specific HTML-Code for the homepage (frontpage).

Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy to understand which template is invoked in which case.

Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags for Conditional Tags, which you can use e.g. in the`header.php`

Comment: thank you.  You really saved me.  I created a front-page.php and put my code in, and it worked!  There were some issues; a custom sidebar template called page-right isn't shown.  But I have used a sidebar widget to replace that content.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) instead.

```
if(is_front_page()){
```

`is_home` works if you have blog posts displaying on the homepage and `is_front_page` if the homepage is set as a static page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It just occurred to me when I opened the header.php that there is no doctype in the homepage.php template file.  Do you think that could be it?  Can I add the doctype into the file just like any other?

Comment: Possibly, the doctype should be added.

Comment: Nope, adding Doctype didn't work. I have even tried adding the HTML to the index page instead but doing that won't make it show either.  I seem to be doing something fundamentally wrong if the HTML will only show by way of the header. edit - I have tried making a template and calling it  from the homepage with <?php get_template_part('box-template'); ?> and get_header(); ?>, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: And using is_front_page() in the header.php file doesn't work either?

Comment: Thanks Howlin. The code works fine if I add it to header php, it's just that it shows on every other page too.  I just want the html boxes to show on the homepage.  But, when I add it to homepage.php or index.php it won't show at all?  is_front_page() is on the index.php.  I'm not sure if you mean something else.

Comment: What is the homepage? Is it a regular page or post or a page set as a front page template?